# After Updating NDK Build is not generating

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, cmake, android-ndk

I have updated the Android Studio to the latest updates and since then the NDK is throwing an error. Before the update, everything was building smoothly. I have no idea about the error. If someone can help. Thanks.

> Build command failed.
>   Error while executing process /Users/blabla/Library/Android/sdk/cmake/3.6.4111459/bin/cmake with arguments {--build /Users/blabla/AndroidStudioProjects/blablanow/mblabla/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/individualDebug/x86 --target mblabla}
>   [1/1] Linking CXX shared library ../../../../build/intermediates/cmake/individual/debug/obj/x86/libmblabla.so
>   FAILED: : && /Users/blabla/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang++  --target=i686-none-linux-android --gcc-toolchain=/Users/blabla/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/x86-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64 --sysroot=/Users/blabla/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot -fPIC -isystem /Users/blabla/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/i686-linux-android -D__ANDROID_API__=19 -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -mstackrealign -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security -std=c++11  -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -Wl,--exclude-libs,libgcc.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libatomic.a -nostdlib++ --sysroot /Users/blabla/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-19/arch-x86 -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--warn-shared-textrel -Wl,--fatal-warnings -L/Users/blabla/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libs/x86 -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Qunused-arguments -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -shared -Wl,-soname,libmblabla.so -o ../../../../build/intermediates/cmake/individual/debug/obj/x86/libmblabla.so CMakeFiles/mblabla.dir/src/main/jni/mblabla_main.cpp.o CMakeFiles/mblabla.dir/src/main/jni/mblablaJNI.cpp.o CMakeFiles/mblabla.dir/src/main/jni/Constants.cpp.o  -llog -latomic -lm "/Users/blabla/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/x86/libgnustl_static.a" && :
>   /Users/blabla/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/stdexcept:136: error: undefined reference to 'std::logic_error::logic_error(char const*)'
>   /Users/blabla/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/stdexcept:136: error: undefined reference to 'std::logic_error::logic_error(char const*)'
>   clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
>   ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

Comment: See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-ndk/3iKT-kLEGpY  (in particular the last message by Dan Albert)

Answer (score 9):

As the comment says (leaving an actual answer for better visibility), see https://groups.google.com/d/topic/android-ndk/3iKT-kLEGpY/discussion.

It seems like CMake isn't updating everything it ought to.

With Studio, the easiest way to resolve this is to follow the advice left by gjs:

> - eventually resolved ok after doing 'Refresh Linked C++ Projects' from the Android Studio Build Menu.

If using CMake outside of Studio: purge your build directory.

Answer (score 2):

Only worked for me with:

1. `rm -rf app/.externalNativeBuild`
2. menu -> Build -> `Refresh linked C++ Project`
3. Make Project (`Ctrl+F9`)

this fixed the next **ndk 17** error:

```
stdexcept:136: error: undefined reference to 'std::logic_error:
```

Answer (score -1):

Do you need uninstall NDK (`Appearance & Behavior > System settings > Android SDK`) and download old release NDK from https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/older_releases

Unzip and copy to empty folder {android-sdk}/ndk-bundle

```
Build > Refresh Linked C++ Projects
```

Comment: "Don't" is not a good answer for "How do I get the new version to work?"